# Sudo Command Missing

Tags: command-line, 22.04, sudo

The Sudo command is missing on a ubuntu machine and I can't do an apt-get update because I don't have access to the root password any ideas?

Comment: Is this your system or run by someone else?  If it's not your system, then you need to contact the admins of that system.  It's not uncommon for people to remove `sudo` if users added to the system are not allowed to be doing admin tasks.

Comment: Try this: https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-sudo-command-not-found-on-linux/ This is the answer that worked for me. Hopefully you'll be sudoing soon!

Answer (score 2):

In a terminal type:

```
which sudo
```

That should give you an output of something like:

```
/usr/bin/sudo
```

If that doesn't, then it's not installed on the machine. The only way to use the superuser account in that case is:

```
su -
```

It will ask for a password, but if you don't know the password for the root account you're not getting into the machine at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `su -` command to log in as the root to install `sudo` tool. This will ask you to give the admin password. In Ubuntu, this is a random string that was generated by the OS during the installation. So you don't have a way to know it. There is a way to change the root password. But unfortunately, you need `sudo` command for that also.

So you have to reinstall Ubuntu on your machine.

Comment: Not necessarily... If the computer is not encrypted you can pop over to a Ubuntu live disk, mount the partition of the dive, change your passwords (for root), and then copy over the /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow files and get into it. Although that is pretty "hacky" it's valid recovery technique. I'm mostly mentioning it here to let people know that the unencrypted filesystem is unsafe. :D

Reinstall should be a last ditch thing.